# Is there a way to change multiple Dictionary values at once in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class with a Dictionary property containing a long list of boolean values that default to false in the constructor. After the object is created I need to change some amount of these to `true` depending on other factors, my question is, is there a more efficient way to change multiple values to `true` than a list of value assignments?

**EDIT:**
I'm helping a student create a game, he has Room object and each room has 8 possible exits. He wants to define each room's exits individually the way he thinks they should be. He decided to make it a Dictionary and he was then defining a Dictionary with 8 true/false values in each Room constructor. I suggested starting with a Dictionary of all falses and only changing the ones he needed to be true (a small percentage of most). Since there is no pattern loops and functions don't really work for what he's trying to do, he needs to enter it manually but I was looking for a way to DRY his code up.

```
Dictionary<int, bool> dict = new Dictionary<int, bool>()
{
    {1, false},
    {2, false},
    {3, false},
    {4, false},
    {5, false},
    {6, false},
    {7, false},
    {8, false}
};

myObject1.dict[1] = true;
myObject1.dict[3] = true;
myObject1.dict[4] = true;
myObject2.dict[3] = true;
myObject3.dict[1] = true;
myObject3.dict[5] = true;
...
```

Comment: Which possible factors to update a values do you have?

Comment: Why not just initialize the dict with a loop? If you know the value when you initialize it, why initialize it incorrectly and then update it?

Comment: I'm helping a student create a game, he has Room object and each room has 8 possible exits.  He wants to define each room individually the way he thinks it should be. He decided to make it a Dictionary and he was then defining a Dictionary with 8 true/false values in each Room constructor, I suggested starting with all falses and only changing the ones he needed to be true (a small percentage of most).

Since there is no pattern looks and functions don't really work for what he's trying to do.

Comment: @arsy does it make sense to use x number of random numbers? if these numbers that need to be updated are coming from his head, I dont think any logic will work :)

Comment: @Jawad I wish there was a way to make it random or patterned in some way, but no, he knows what each room looks like in his head and I'm just trying to help him simplify the amount of code he needs to write to create that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there's a more efficient way but there's a more "compact" way, without looping through all of the keys of each dictionary :

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, bool>()
{
    {1, false},
    {2, false},
    {3, false},
    {4, false},
    {5, false},
    {6, false}
};

new List<int> { 1, 3, 4 }.ForEach(i => myObject1.dict[i] = true);
new List<int> { 3       }.ForEach(i => myObject2.dict[i] = true);
new List<int> { 1, 5    }.ForEach(i => myObject3.dict[i] = true);
```

Comment: This is a really interesting answer, and might be the closest to what he wants to do that I've seen so far.  I'll have him test it out, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to update multiple records in a dictionary based on a condition.

Following example simply changes the values of every even numbered key. You can use your own condition in the Where clause to get the specific keys that you need to update.

```
dict.Where(x => x.Key % 2 == 0).ToList().ForEach(x => dict[x.Key] = true);
```

**Randomly choose the doors**

You can also work it out where you update the dictionary based on certain random numbers.

```
int numOfDoors = 4;
List<int> randomNumber = Enumerable.Range(0, numOfDoors).Select(x => new Random().Next(1, dict.Count())).ToList();
dict.Where(x => randomNumber.Contains(x.Key)).ToList().ForEach(x => dict[x.Key] = true);
```

Comment: This is going to loop over all the the entries in the dictionary and create a list of the KeyValuePairs that match and then loop over that list to set the values.  It would be more efficient to not use `ToList` and just use a normal `foreach` on the result of the query.

Comment: Well... Dictionaries does not contain a definition of foreach. To use `ForEach`, you have to convert the dictionary to KeyValuePair list. ForEach is a definition for List of KeyValuePair.

Comment: You don't need a `ForEach` method, just do `foreach(var kvp in dict.Where(x => x.Key % 2 == 0)) { dic[kvp.Key] = true; }`.  You should only use `ForEach` when you already have a `List`.  Doing `ToList` just to use the `ForEach` method is a bad practice.

Comment: @juharr it will throw invalid operation exception, collection was changed error

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method such as this:

```
void SetMultipleKeyValues(Dictionary<int,bool> dictionary, bool value, params int[] keys)
{
  foreach(int key in keys) 
  {
    dictionary[key] = value;
  }
}
```

It's a simplistic example, you could make it a generic extension method, use LINQ instead of a foreach loop, etc. It would encapsulate the looping well so that you aren't replicating it everywhere you need to set the list of values in your dictionary.

Jeff

Comment: I edited the post to clarify- the problem is there is no pattern to follow. I need to make unique edits to the dictionaries of each object, so I have to do in manually in the code not with methods or loops.